# Android: Launch Application on Lock key longpress Click

Tags: java, android, android-keypad

I want to invoke my application on longpress Click of lock key.
Actually the shut down dialog will appear.
I want to override that one.

Is this possible???

Answer (score 1):

**Its not Possible**, Without customized Android OS. Or writing own Launcher Application. Because of Android OS Security Concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I think its beyond the scope of your application. Either you have to get the root access to your mobile or write a launcher app...

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to the phone and have the ability to write your own ROM, you can invoke your option in the lock menu, but as the others says, you cant without more control of the rom.

My recomendation is to head over to: xda-developers.org and ask around.

You application will probably be device dependent.